# SQL: delete from joint tables where count condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these tables:

**tutors**:

```
email firstname, lastname...
```

**courses**:

```
url  tutorid description
```

**reviews**:

```
review courseid author
```

`author` in `reviews` and `tutorid` in `courses` is foreign key = tutors.email.

I need to delete all tutors that have 2 or more courses without a description.

I first tried to just select such tutors:

```
select tutors.email, COUNT(courses.url) 
from courses 
left join tutors on courses.tutorid = tutors.email
where 

description is null group by (tutors.email);
```

this works fine. However I'm not sure how to delete the tutors with the given emails, considering the tutors.email is a foreign key in other tables.

Comment: . . You won't be able to do this if you have properly declared foreign key relationships.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Won't be able to delete things from the tables? How do all the sites do that then?

Comment: . . They would delete the rows in the table that reference `tutors` as well.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes, that's what I want. To delete a tutor once and for all from all tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't delete the records in related tables that contains the foreign key, you will eventually create something called orphaned records, and that is something that goes against the referential integrity rule in general in RDBMS. 
It is also possible that the RDBMS will enforce referential integrity, and you wont be able to do that before you delete all the associate records in the other tables first.